# jest mock functions but keep some original code for others?

Tags: javascript, express, jestjs

Scenario is, I have a function that needs to be unit tested: `AppleLoginService()`.

It will contain 3 other functions within it. These need to be mocked. Simple.

```js
//UserService.js
const AppleLoginService = async () => {
    await verifyAppleToken();
    const response = await verifyAuthorizationCode(authorizationCode);
    const id = await RegisterIdpAccount(); //Can ignore for now.
    return {id}
}

async function verifyAppleToken() { 
//etc code
}
async function verifyAuthorizationCode() {
//etc code
}
```

The issue is, I need to retain `AppleLoginService` original code but mock everything else but cannot do so.

I've tried:

- But obviously, mocks `AppleLoginService` which isn't what I want.

```
jest.mock("UserService");
```

- The functions doesn't actually get mocked in this way which is weird. I've put logs in the functions and ends up printing.

```
jest.mock("UserService", () => {
    const original = jest.requireActual("UserService");
    return {
        ...original,
        verifyAppleToken: jest.fn(),
        verifyAuthorizationCode: jest.fn()
    }
});
```

- Also doesn't get mocked. Original implementation runs.

```
const verifyToken = jest.spyOn(services, "verifyAppleToken").mockImplementation(() => true);
const verifyCode = jest.spyOn(services, "verifyAuthorizationCode").mockImplementation(() => 1);
```

```
const services = require("UserService.js");
const queries = require("SQLTransactionService.js"));

/*
jest.mock() ETC
*/

describe("When using AppleLoginService,", () => {
    it("given all values are correct then, return response", async () => {

        services.verifyAppleToken.mockReturnValueOnce(true);
        services.verifyAuthorizationCode.mockResolvedValueOnce("ANYTHING");
        queries.RegisterIdpAccount.mockResolvedValueOnce(1);

        const res = await services.AppleLoginService("apple", signUpPayload);

        expect(services.verifyAppleToken).toBeCalledTimes(1); // Is called 0 times
        expect(services.verifyAuthorizationCode).toBeCalledTimes(1); // Is called 0 times.
        expect(res).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you give more detail regarding the file where AppleLoginService is defined e.g. are the functions within it, verifyAppleToken for example, defined in this file?

Comment: @BenSmith
 `RegisterIdpAccount` is in `SQLTransactionService.js`;
The rest is in `UserService.js`;